# eclipse deleting imports it doesn't find

Tags: eclipse, clojure

Is there a way to stop Eclipse's "organize imports" from deleting imports it can't find? In this case, it's not being able to locate a class that's built using Clojure. I'd like the organize imports feature to run otherwise.

Comment: +1 for asking about a useful feature. I feel like I've managed to do this before, but don't recall if this was in Eclipse and if it was in Eclipse, I don't recall how it was done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this cannot be achieved with JDT.